# Why main thread is blocked?

Tags: java, multithreading

My requirement is that, user will enter some values in the main thread continuously and the worker thread will take those values and run in background without blocking main thread and when worker thread is done with execution then it will return value to the main thread.

I have this following code Main.java

```
 private static ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
            Future<String> result = service.submit(new GerUserQuery());
            System.out.println("Get result" + result.get());
            callSomeMethod();
        } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
            service.shutdown();

}
```

And the GerUserQuery.java

```
public class GerUserQuery implements Callable<String>{

@Override
public String call() throws Exception {
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    performIOOperation();
    return  " hello world" ;
  }
 }
```

What I am trying to do is that, the main thread will continue its execution after this line of codes without waiting for the worker thread to return the result.

```
  Future<String> result = service.submit(new GerUserQuery());
            System.out.println("Get result" + result.get());
```

The problem I have is that, the main thread is always waiting and once  worker thread to return the result then `callSomeMethod()`is called.
How should I proceed?

Comment: What does `performIOOperation()` do?

Comment: @GiorgiTsiklauri, it calls REST API

Comment: The documentation for `Future.get()` says it blocks, so if you don't want to block you don't call `get()`.  Now if you'll explain your actual requirements in more detail, maybe we can help you.

Comment: @markspace, I have chatbot app, where user will enter value is chat window. Once user enters value then I have to make REST call to get the data, but REST call can take several minutes , so during this time the main thread should accept user input. And once worker thread is done then I want to return the result to main thread.

Comment: Well we'll need to see an api for returning a result to your chat room or whatever.  How does one send a result to this "chat?"

Answer (score 2):

This is why it is blocked:

```
            System.out.println("Get result" + result.get());
```

You are asking for a result with a get operation that is blocking the main thread.
The result should return async, and not as "get"

Remove the log to get what you want

EDIT :

To get your result, you need to open a new thread, or you something that does it for you

Either :

```
new Thread() {
@Override
  public void run(){ 
      result.get(); //this will give you your result.
  }
 }.start();
```

I would suggest looking into [Retrofit](https://square.github.io/retrofit/) as your async lib, and then you could do something like this:

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
.baseUrl("https://api.github.com/")
.build();

 GitHubService service = 
  retrofit.create(GitHubService.class);
service.listRepos().enqueue({ 
     @Override
     public void onResponse () {
          //your result here
      }
 });
```

I didn't fill in the full method declarations, the compiler and auto complete should help you with that

Comment: thanks for your help, if I remove the `result.get()`then how do I return the value to the main thread?